# How to code a BottomSheet like view that can be dismissed upwards or downwards

Tags: android, android-layout, bottom-sheet

I've been searching all over the internet over the last couple of days, to no avail. I'm trying to code something like a `BottomSheetDialog` that can be dismissed (swiped out of view) either upwards or downwards.

If such a view would be coded from scratch, the use case would be as follows: The view fills the entire screen, and can be dragged up or down (only vertical movement). When dragged and released the view should have a velocity and keep moving accordingly. Once the view moves off screen, a callback should fire, indicating whether the view was moving upwards or downwards.

I don't expect the answer to be handed to me. I'm assuming I'd have to code something like this from the ground up. I just have no idea where to start. Which Android components (`ViewDragHelper`, etc) could I use to create something like this? I've had some success with just an `OnTouchListener`, checking for the `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` flag and using the received motion event's data to modify the view's `LayoutParams` as shown [here](http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/how-to-drag-a-view-in-android). How would I then go about velocity?

Comment: A good start for you will be watching [Nick Butcher](https://twitter.com/crafty?ref_src=twsrc%5Egoogle%7Ctwcamp%5Eserp%7Ctwgr%5Eauthor)'s ["Animatable" presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=86p1GPEv_fY), where he explains how he implemented such a feature in his open-source [Plaid app](https://github.com/nickbutcher/plaid).

Comment: Thanks @azizbekian I'm watching the video now

Comment: @azizbekian Plaid has exactly what I need to learn from! Thank you so much. I'll post an answer as soon as the code is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up modifying [BottomSheet](https://github.com/nickbutcher/plaid/blob/master/app/src/main/java/io/plaidapp/ui/widget/BottomSheet.java) from the Plaid app, as suggested by @azizbekian.

The most notable changes were made in the `computeSettleDuration` method and in `clampViewPositionVertical` callback found in `ViewDragHelper.Callback`.

It was surprisingly easy to get it working as intended. The source code can be viewed [here](https://gist.github.com/lyfebegins/4aa3638ea2f3120c0cb19d8556dc1e2b).